# Attribute error in python while parsing an XML

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am kinda new to Python. I am working on a project that parses an XML in Python and my Python code to do so is :

```python
from xml.dom import minidom
from copy import copy

class Xmlparse:


    def __init__(self, xmlfile):
        self = minidom.parse(xmlfile)

    def findadress(self):
        itemlist =self.getElementsByTagName('addresses')
        return itemlist[0].attributes['firstname'].value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("sample.xml") as f:

        parse = Xmlparse(f)
        print parse.findadress()
```

But when I run this code I get an output error:

```
AttributeError: Xmlparse instance has no attribute 'findadress'
```

And findadress function is spelled correctly in the main, but for some reason what so ever i am getting this error.

Any help is really appreciated.

And I also wanted to know, how can I validate the xml with an XSD schema in python?

Comment: its better to create another thread for ` validate the xml with an XSD schema`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"self = minidom.parse(xmlfile)" overwrites the Xmlparse object you just created. You want to assign the xml doc to a variable instead:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from copy import copy

class Xmlparse:

    def __init__(self, xmlfile):
        self.doc = minidom.parse(xmlfile)

    def findadress(self):
        itemlist =self.doc.getElementsByTagName('addresses')
        return itemlist[0].attributes['firstname'].value
```

Answer (score 0):

the evil is in `self = minidom.parse(xmlfile)`

Comment: and what exactly is that evil?

Comment: Down voted. Why? It's incorrect, but shouldn't raise AttributeError. Please explain better. (Code for reference: http://bpaste.net/show/77934/)

Comment: @spaniard89: you are replacing the newly created `Xmlparse` instance with `minidom.parse(xmlfile)` output.

Comment: @frb, it's clear, the minidom.parse(xmlfile) output has no attribute findaddress.

Comment: you're assigning to a class' instance (self) in the very class' constructor something irrelevant. Just don't do this. Assign to instance's attribute instead.

Comment: @pylover And the integer `0` doesn't have an attribute `test`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply. I understood the problem now.